# how do I scan the windows partition for malware?

Tags: linux, security, dual-boot, malware, secure-boot

Hopefully, not too broad of a question.

For Windows 10, I was considering dual booting at least for the purposes of malware detection and removal.  While AVG, and probably others, offer live rescue discs, what is feasible from an outside source?

Ideally I would use a laptop running Linux to scan the windows pc, but let's assume a dual-boot scenario.  Can I "install" AVG, Kaspersky, et. al. "to" Linux to scan another partition on the same hard drive?

The target pc uses secure boot, UEFI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part an AV just scans files. It will remove malicious Windows payloads when running on Linux (and vice versa). The detection doesn't depend on the host architecture or operating system at all, as malware code is not being run by the AV at runtime. So, as long as you mount your Windows NTFS partition somewhere under Linux, you can tell your Linux AV to scan the files in it for malware (or just let it do it's default thing where it scans all possible filesystems).

Thus you are just plain looking for Linux AV software, with no special requirements.