# Windows anti-virus and anti-malware available on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, windows, administration, malware

In relation to [scanning a Windows partition for malware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330214/how-do-i-scan-the-windows-partition-for-malware) I see that both [AVG](https://www.unixmen.com/install-avg-free-antivirus-on-ubuntu/) and [Avast](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-and-update-avast-antivirus-in-ubuntu) install on Linux painlessly.  Is there a full list of free-as-in-beer Windows anti-virus, or general anti-malware *for Windows*, available from Linux?

Comment: Why would you need _Windows_ antivirus software on Linux?

Comment: to fix a windows machine.  AVG distributes a live rescue disk, figured might as well just use my laptop.

Comment: You want to fix a Windows machine remotely from a Linux machine using Windows antivirus software?

Comment: Possibly remotely.  At least initially, they would be side by side.  Two laptops.

Comment: OK, you're kidding, right?

Comment: why?  AVG has a rescue disk for a thumb drive which runs on Linux.  Why not just install AVG directly on my laptop.  not any more difficult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50136/discussion-between-thufir-and-schaiba).

Comment: Clam AV and rkhunter to check it on linux. Some commercial anti Virus are available on linux too.

Comment: Not free, but NOD32 rocks - runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux. I ran it on a bench file server that was fixing Windows PCs for 2.5 years. NOD32  detects all the same malware, regardless of which OS the product was installed on - except Android. https://www.eset.com/us/home/antivirus-linux/

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia says:

For Microsoft Windows-specific threats

These applications are useful for computers (typically, servers) which will pass on files to MS Windows users. They do not look for Linux-specific threats.

```
Avast! (proprietary; freeware version available)
AVG (proprietary; freeware version available)
Avira (proprietary; freeware version was available, discontinued due to lack of demand)[10]
BitDefender (proprietary; freeware version available)
Comodo (proprietary; freeware version available) [11]
ClamAV (free and open source software)[12]
Dr.Web (proprietary) [13]
EScan for Linux (proprietary)
F-Prot (proprietary; freeware version available)[14]
F-Secure Linux (proprietary)
Kaspersky Linux Security (proprietary)[15]
McAfee VirusScan Enterprise for Linux (proprietary)[16]
Panda Security for Linux (proprietary)[17]
Sophos (proprietary) (versions for UNIX and Linux too)
Symantec AntiVirus for Linux (proprietary)[18]
Trend Micro ServerProtect for Linux (proprietary)
```

from:

https://askubuntu.com/a/229065/45156